# SIEM DSCC - Upgrade Fails and then web console doesn't shows anything

Tags: web-application

Since trying to patch, we can not access the Web Interface, the Console page is empty.

We also tried to upgrade trough CLI but it returns this error messages

---

Checking for undeployed changes...
Found undeployed changes!
[PATCH_UPDATER] [ERROR] The patch cannot continue because you have undeployed changes in your system.
[PATCH_UPDATER] [ERROR] Please go to the Administration Console and deploy changes before continuing with the patch.
An error was encountered attempting to process patches.
Please contact customer support for further assistance.

---

Check the Build Version of DSCC

```
[root@NOCMSIEM1 ~]# cat /opt/qradar/conf/build_version
7.1.0.414913
```

Before we start we did a backup of the configuration.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nobody 57428857 Sep 19 12:51 backup.BackupUpgrade.NOCMSIEM1_3.19_09_2013.config.1379587862604.tgz
```

I don't have experience and have never worked with this console. But looking through the internet I have seen similar errors in your forum and I think you maybe could help me, I think the error is related to the tomcat.

```
/opt/tomcat6/logs/catalina.2013-09-23.log
------------------
Sep 25, 2013 3:10:14 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Sep 25, 2013 3:10:14 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Sep 25, 2013 3:10:14 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=1/14  config=null
Sep 25, 2013 3:10:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 6132 ms
Sep 25, 2013 3:10:14 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Sep 25, 2013 3:10:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Sep 25, 2013 3:10:15 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Sep 25, 2013 3:10:24 PM org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm setUseContextClassLoader
INFO: Setting useContextClassLoader = false
Sep 25, 2013 3:10:24 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Realm} Setting property 'debug' to '99' did not find a matching property.
Sep 25, 2013 3:10:24 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Sep 25, 2013 3:10:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 355 ms
Sep 25, 2013 3:10:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 25, 2013 3:10:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
Sep 25, 2013 3:10:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory console
Sep 25, 2013 3:10:29 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener contextInitialized
INFO: WSSERVLET12: JAX-WS context listener initializing
Sep 25, 2013 3:10:30 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate <init>
**INFO: WSSERVLET14: JAX-WS servlet initializing
Sep 25, 2013 3:10:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Sep 25, 2013 3:10:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/console] startup failed due to previous errors**
Sep 25, 2013 3:10:30 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate destroy
INFO: WSSERVLET15: JAX-WS servlet destroyed
Sep 25, 2013 3:10:30 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener contextDestroyed
INFO: WSSERVLET13: JAX-WS context listener destroyed
Sep 25, 2013 3:10:30 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Sep 25, 2013 3:10:30 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Sep 25, 2013 3:10:30 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/13  config=null
Sep 25, 2013 3:10:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
```

We have restored from the backup settings and reboot the appliance several times and have not gotten to load the DSCC web interface.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about deploying and configuring enterprise-level software and utilities. It should be migrated to [SF].